# Doouble Looopiing

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to print out "OK" value if the statements same value with "NumberPallete" but my code doesn't work right.

I have two conditions to compare from one cell value ["54# / 221"]. The first condition value for "SeriesNumber" is [88] and then the Second condition value for "NumberPallete" is [221#]. I am using looping for "SeriesNumber" and "NumberPallete" to find the value because I have long data in the table sheet.

and then from the different sheets using looping too, I am starting with the First condition checks "SeriesNumber" value if the value is right, then check the second condition from "NumberPallete" value, in this condition, I want a print out "ok" value but "ok" value doesn't print out.

I am sorry, my English is poor. I'm trying my best to explain. Please help me.

```
Dim NumberPallete As String
Dim SeriesNumber As String

Dim I As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim z As Long

i = Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row

For j = 6 To i

    'Cells(j, 20).Value = Right(Cells(j, 15).Value, Len(Cells(j, 15)) - InStr(1, Cells(j, 15).Value, "/"))
    SeriesNumber = Right(Cells(j, 15).Value, Len(Cells(j, 15)) - InStr(1, Cells(j, 15).Value, "/"))
    
    'Cells(j, 21).Value = Left(Cells(j, 15).Value, Len(Cells(j, 15)) - InStr(1, Cells(j, 15).Value, "/"))
    NumberPallete = Left(Cells(j, 15).Value, Len(Cells(j, 15)) - InStr(1, Cells(j, 15).Value, "/"))
    
        If SeriesNumber = 221 Then

            For z = 4 To 250
                                 
                If Worksheets("AAA").Cells(z, 2).Value = NumberPallete Then
                    
                    Worksheets("AAA").Cells(z, 6).Value = "OK"
                                                                                                   
                End If
            
            Next z
                    
        Else
        
        MsgBox ("Not OK")
        
        End If

Next j
```

Comment: Please add some precise data examples... it's not clear enough to debug your code.
Most probably your formulas to calculate SeriesNumber and NumberPallete are not perfect, you may have leftover "blanks" which are not easy to spot.
I would add an `MsgBox` like `"-" & SeriesNumber & "-"` after the calculation of SeriesNumber to be able to spot such errors. Same for NumberPallete.

Comment: Why do you do this to yourself? Split the following statement `SeriesNumber = Right(Cells(j, 15).Value, Len(Cells(j, 15)) - InStr(1, Cells(j, 15).Value, "/"))` into multiple statements and use the debugger to see if they behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I may not have fully understood what you are trying to do but the code below is doing something and, hopefully, it can be fixed to do what you want.

```
Sub FindPalletNumber()
    ' 062
    
    ' you can find code to enter 2 values with input boxes at this link:-
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62651211/vba-excel-search-in-excel-specific-word-and-delete-all-rows-who-does-not-have-t
    
    Dim Snum        As Integer              ' serial number
    Dim Pnum        As Integer              ' pallet number
    Dim Txt         As String               ' message text
    
    Snum = 221                              ' number only
    Pnum = 54                               ' no # sign, no brackets
    
    If MarkOK(Snum, Pnum) Then
        Txt = "Found and marked."
    Else
        Txt = "No match found."
    End If
    MsgBox Txt, vbInformation, "Action report"
End Sub

Private Function MarkOK(Snum As Integer, _
                        Pnum As Integer) As Boolean
    ' 062
    ' return True if found and marked

    Const Pallet        As Long = 0         ' element of array Nums
    Const Serial        As Long = 1         ' element of array Nums
    
    Dim Nums()          As String           ' split cell pattern "54# / 221"
    Dim Done            As Boolean          ' True if found
    Dim R               As Long             ' loop counter: Row in ActiveSheet
    Dim R2              As Long             ' loop counter: Row in Ws("AAA")
    
    For R = 6 To Cells(Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
        Nums = Split(Cells(R, 15).Value, "/")
        ' Nums(Pallet) = "54# ", Nums(Serial) = " 221"
        
        If Val(Nums(Serial)) = Snum Then
            With Worksheets("AAA")
                For R2 = 4 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
                    If .Cells(R2, 2).Value = Trim(Nums(Pallet)) Then
                       .Cells(R2, 6).Value = "OK"
                       Done = True
                       Exit For
                    End If
                Next R2
            End With
        End If
        If Done Then Exit For               ' stop search if found
    Next R
    MarkOK = Done
End Function
```

In the first procedure the Pallet and Serial numbers should be set (*Pnum* and *Snum*). Then, when you run that procedure, it will call the other one which reports back whether a match was found or not. I have added a link where you can find code to get the two values from Input boxes, if that is what you need.

The function looks for the serial number in the ActiveSheet. If found, it looks for the pallet number in Sheet("AAA"). This is confusing because it looks for the pallet number found in the ActiveSheet, not the pallet number specified in the search. The pallet number in the search specs ends up not being used at all. Perhaps it's not needed.

Anyway, when the pallet is found the row is marked and the search terminates. If the pallet number isn't found the loop in the ActiveSheet is continued to look for another instance of the serial number. Note that the code is not enabled to find multiple pallets with the same serial number.